# incorrect two-way binding in angular 2 components

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement two-way binding in angular 2.
I have the following parent component:

**app.component.html**:

```
<child [(text)]="childText" (textChanged)="textChanged($event)"></child>
<span>{{childText}}</span>
```

**app.components.ts**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  childText = 'My text';

  textChanged(newValue: string) {
    console.log(this.childText); // this.childText is equal "My text" always 
    console.log(newValue); // output new value from child input
  }
}
```

**child.component.html**:

```
<input #inputEl [value]="text" (keyup)="text = inputEl.value">
```

**child.component.ts**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: 'child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent {
  private _text: string;
  @Output() textChanged: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  @Input()
  get text(): string {
    return this._text;
  }

  set text(value) {
    this._text = value;
    this.textChanged.emit(value);
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

When I change text in `input` of `child` component then `{{childText}}` from `app` component template takes new value, but `this.childText` is still has default value ("My text").

I can change `AppComponent.childText` in `AppComponent.textChanged`:

```
this.childText = newValue;
```

But is it possible to change `this.childText` without callback from `child` component?

And why `<span>{{childText}}</span>` takes new value only?

Comment: Why would you create wheel from scratch when it already exists? Use `NgModel` directive for two way data binding.

Comment: where is `inputText` declared?

Comment: @shusson sorry, it was my mistake. I've changed inputText to childText

Comment: to simplify the problem, can you make `text` public and remove the getter and setter?

Comment: @shusson see http://plnkr.co/edit/NV9waVbYfQRoYTMCq3Rv where text is just @Input() text: string;

Comment: @StefanSvrkota could you write an example for my case where NgModel helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for two way binding using `[(x)]` is a property called `x` and a corresponding event named `xChange`. You had just had a typo in `textChanged`.

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() text: string;
  @Output() textChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  onKeyUp(val) {
    this.text = val;
    this.textChange.emit(this.text);
  }
  ...
}
```